# External eimp process has terminated unexpectedly

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I configured ejabberd, when I am trying to start my ejabberd server by using

```
ejabberdctl start
```

command, the server is working fine but in log file I can see the error as **External eimp process has terminated unexpectedly, restarting in a few seconds**

My log data as,

```
2017-10-04 18:47:03.668 [notice] <0.55.0>@lager_file_backend:146 Changed loghwm of /usr/local/var/log/ejabberd/error.log to 100
2017-10-04 18:47:03.668 [notice] <0.55.0>@lager_file_backend:146 Changed loghwm of /usr/local/var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log to 100
2017-10-04 18:47:03.712 [info] <0.7.0> Application lager started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.718 [info] <0.7.0> Application crypto started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.759 [info] <0.7.0> Application sasl started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.766 [info] <0.7.0> Application asn1 started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.766 [info] <0.7.0> Application public_key started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.772 [info] <0.7.0> Application ssl started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.773 [info] <0.7.0> Application p1_utils started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.809 [info] <0.7.0> Application fast_yaml started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.830 [info] <0.7.0> Application fast_tls started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.843 [info] <0.7.0> Application fast_xml started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.846 [info] <0.7.0> Application stringprep started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.858 [info] <0.7.0> Application xmpp started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.862 [info] <0.7.0> Application cache_tab started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:03.890 [error] <0.139.0> External eimp process (pid=21948) has terminated unexpectedly, restarting in a few seconds
2017-10-04 18:47:03.989 [error] <0.141.0> External eimp process (pid=21949) has terminated unexpectedly, restarting in a few seconds
2017-10-04 18:47:04.073 [error] <0.143.0> External eimp process (pid=21950) has terminated unexpectedly, restarting in a few seconds
2017-10-04 18:47:04.155 [info] <0.7.0> Application eimp started on node ejabberd@localhost
2017-10-04 18:47:04.156 [info] <0.38.0>@ejabberd_config:start:73 Loading configuration from /usr/local/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml
2017-10-04 18:47:04.156 [error] <0.145.0> External eimp process (pid=21951) has terminated unexpectedly, restarting in a few seconds
2017-10-04 18:47:04.526 [error] <0.141.0> External eimp process (pid=21952) has terminated unexpectedly, restarting in a few seconds
2017-10-04 18:47:05.266 [info] <0.7.0> Application mnesia started on node ejabberd@localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instaling "erlang" from epel-repository

Answer (score 0):

Not resolved. I have installed erlang from epel repository as well as built it from sources but the error remains there.

I have erlang from epel: **erlang-R16B-03.18.el7.x86_64**
and **erlang/OTP 20** built from sources.